# Command works from bash prompt; does not work from within shell script

Tags: bash, scripting, shell, shell-scripting, ipmitool

I'm trying to use IPMITOOL to query a bunch of OOB NICs to get their MAC addresses.

When I run:

```
 ipmitool -I lanplus -H 1.2.3.4 -U USER -P PASS lan print
```

I get:

```
MAC Address             : aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff
```

If I try to call it via a shell script that iterates over a CSV file:

```
#!/bin/bash
INPUT=/home/user/list_of_systems.csv
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=','
while read hostname ipaddr
do
        printf "$hostname\t" >> output.txt
        ipmitool -I lanplus -H $ipaddr -U USER -P PASS lan print
done < $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

I get:

```
 failed lookup for 1.2.3.4
Could not open socket!
Error: Unable to establish IPMI v2 / RMCP+ session
```

What am I missing here?  I have been tearing my hair out over this.

Comment: What's the difference between your environment and the sudo environment?

Comment: Oh, derp.  The sudo was from testing, not when I ran it.  I'll delete.  Good catch.

Comment: Does the input file have `\r\n` line endings? Run with `bash -x script.sh` and see if you can spot any unusual values for ipaddr

Comment: We have a winner!  That did it.  I saw the \r, converted the line endings, and blam, it worked!  If you want to post this as an actual answer, I'll mark it as complete ASAP.

Comment: Are you setting `IFS` just to control how `read` splits fields? If so, make the assignment a prefix to the `read` command (`while IFS=',' read hostname ipaddr`) so it only affects that one command and you don't have to deal with `OLDIFS`. I'd also recommend double-quoting variables (e.g. `"$ipaddr"` instead of just `$ipaddr`), and keeping format and data separate (`printf "%s\t" "$hostname"` instead of printf "$hostname\t"`). [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will spot some of these -- I recommend running all your scripts through it to see what problems it spots.

Comment: Oh, and `while IFS=$',\r' read ...` will auto-trim carriage returns from the end of lines as it reads.

Answer (score 0):

Per https://serverfault.com/users/30957/glenn-jackman I had bad line endings in the CSV file.  After fixing those, this started to work.